# npx create-strapi-app@latest not working on M1

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to setup a strapi app. I keep getting errors like
`error Couldn't find package "vary@^1.1.2" required by "@koa/cors@3.4.3" on the "npm" registry.` when running `npx create-strapi-app@latest --quickstart --ts my-project`

I'm on latest node version (v18.17.0), python (3.11.4) and sqlite3 (3.39.5).

Has anyone else been facing this issue lately?

Other posts referred to installing dependencies like vips via brew, but that didn't solve the problem for me.

Thanks

Comment: Try with `yarn create strapi-app`